# Redirect browsers that don't support SSL cipers\suites

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'd like to redirect clients that use old browsers to a page that instructs them to download a newer browser.

by "old" browsers I mean - browsers that don't support certain ciper suites \ ssl protocols.
e.g. TLS1.1 or older to go to old.html and TLS1.2 to go to index.html

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Yes you can detect browser versions pretty easily. It is part of the headers send with each request. Matching them up with capabilities is somewhat trickier as is keeping such a list up to date.

No in the sense that your web/application server still need to allow HTTPS access using insecure versions of the SSL protocol and will still support low quality cipher suites. The SSL negotiation is already finished before you can detect the browser version and present the old.html page.

I'm not sure but I assume it is not unlikely that browsers will negiatiotate with an HTTPS server to use the most secure algorith, but it's possible for browser and server to mutually agree on the lowest, most insecure protocol they have in common as well as that will likely also be the most inexpensive computationally ; a valid choice for low power devices.

So even determining the actual cipher suite used may not be accurate in determining that the browser is "old".

Comment: Hi. 
I am actually looking for a way to serve a different page to clients who don't support TLS1.2, so i'd like to resolve this in the Nginx level. e.g. one configuration that serves TLS1.2 clients and another for all the rest.

Comment: Anything unclear in the [nginx manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_browser_module.html)? With again the caveat a browser may support TLS 1.2 and negotiate to not use it.